# how to refer all the external jar files in my batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, solr, jar

Here is my batch file code

```
@echo off
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\example\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpmime-4.2.6.jar;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;
\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;
\solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar\solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar;\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;"
cp=

javac -cp "%cp%" SolrjPopulator.java
java -cp "%cp%" SolrjPopulator
pause
```

after I run the batch file java compiler doesn't find the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\example\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\httpmime-4.2.6.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;.\solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar\solr-solrj-4.0.0.jar;.\solr-4.6.1\solr-4.6.1\dist\solrj-lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;"


javac -cp "%CLASSPATH%" SolrjPopulator.java
java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" SolrjPopulator
pause
```

as a path `\` points to the drive root - you rather need `.\`.There was a new line in the classpath definition.`JAVA` has used a `%CP%` variable instead of `%CLASSPATH%`. And `cp=` is not a command and probably will produce an error.

or if you dont wanna list all the jars manually:

```
@echo off

set "solr_location=.\solr-4.6.1"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd %solr_location%
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    if not defined classpath (
        set "classpath=%%~a"
    else (
        set "classpath=!classpath!;%%~a"
    ) 
)
set "classpath=!classpath!;"
popd

javac -cp "%CLASSPATH%" SolrjPopulator.java
java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" SolrjPopulator
endlocal
pause
```